# Laravel validation error message show only short form

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-request

I got used to request to validate before entering the API side function itself, but recently, when I moved the controller function to services then, the error message became like the below sample.

```
{
    "message": "validation.min.string",
    "errors": {
        "password": [
            "validation.min.string"
        ]
    }
}
```

But when I use the same way build in the new project, the error message show as usual as below

> ```
> {
>     "message": "The name must only contain letters.",
>     "errors": {
>         "name": [
>             "The name must only contain letters."
>         ]
>     }
>  }
> ```

I found that I had added an en language file under res `resources\lang\en,` which caused this issue, so may I know how I can change back to this version without removing the en file? Thanks

Comment: Why do you want `lang` folder insde the `resources` ?

Comment: @xenooooo that's the old method from my senior ><, he use this place to do the matching things.

Comment: why not just copy the `lang` folder to the root folder ?

Comment: If I use the `lang` in `root` file, am I still able to use `trans()` function to get the data from `en` file?

Comment: no, depends what laravel version you are using... Larave 9+ will look for `lang` on the root, not the previous ones... Could you share what that language file looks like?

Comment: @matiaslauriti just now I tested my side the trans function still working my side languages format like ` return [ "key"=> [ "item"=> "translate_item" ] ];`